# Async programming

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

I'm trying below code for my learning on Java 8.

**The output of this code is:**

```
Before Get
Rajeev , Welcome to the CalliCoder Blog
After Get.
```

But as per my understanding on async program the output should have been

**something like:**

```
Before Get
After Get. 
Rajeev , Welcome to the CalliCoder Blog
```

Any comments on this plz.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    CompletableFuture<String> welcomeText = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {

        for(double i=0;i<1000000000;i++) {
            for(double j=0;i<1000000000;i++) {
                for(double k=0;i<1000000000;i++) {
                    for(double l=0;i<1000000000;i++) {
                        for(double m=0;i<1000000000;i++) {
                            for(double n=0;i<1000000000;i++) {
                                for(double o=0;i<1000000000;i++) {

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "Rajeev";
    }).thenApply(name -> {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }).thenApply(greeting -> {
        return greeting + ", Welcome to the CalliCoder Blog";
    });
    System.out.println("Before Get");
    System.out.println(welcomeText.get());
    System.out.println("After Get");
}
```

Comment: How do you expect us to tell you what your mistake is if you won't explain your reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

The call to `welcomeText.get()` blocks until the result is available.

Asynchronous programming doesn't mean things just happen in random order and it's good. You have to have a task that benefits from asynchronous execution. This example has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: Then what is the use of this. I can achieve same by using some simple method right. How can it be a async

Comment: @Geek thats just intro to the CompletableFuture API, once you get comfortable with it, you can start writing asynchronous code

Answer (score 0):

You're are right making a call to .get() doesn't really make sense initially if we are learning about asynchronous programming.

In most Asynchronous scenarios you don't really need to use `.get()` , you would normally use `whenComplete()`

Something like:

```
.whenComplete((s,e) -> {System.out.println("Really Done -> " + s );});
```

Comment out the get() and put a `Thread.Sleep(10)` in the `main()`, normally async is about async IO and CPU intensive operations are not really needed to be async. If you check out netty and other asynchronous libraries in java you will appreciate this much better.